# How to use Monaco library as code formatter?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I need to be able to format code from various languages. For this I am using 3 different libraries for HTML, CSS, and JS, all of which are very large.

To reduce unnecessary code, I would like to use the existing code formatter in the monaco library that I am already using to create a function like this:

```js
function getFormattedCode(code, mimeType/fileExtension) { ... }
```

So far I have been unable to do this efficiently due to the many problems that can be seen here:

```js
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"));

function format(code, fileName) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const model = monaco.editor.createModel(
            code,
            undefined,
            monaco.Uri.file(fileName),
        );

        editor.setModel(model);
        setTimeout(() => {
            editor.getAction("editor.action.formatDocument").run();
            
            setTimeout(() => resolve(model.getValue()), 500);
        }, 100);
    });
}

!async function () {
    alert(await format("x=1", ".js"));
}();
```

Long delays are required and the actual HTML for the editor is being modified unnecessarily.

Is there any way to sort of extract the formatting functionality from the monaco library?